# Decompiling a compiled program with Go

Tags: compiler-construction, go, decompiling

I have built a simple executable program with `Go`.

I've compiled the code into a static binary program.

I want to decompile the output binary file and get the Go source code.

Is this possible or not?

Comment: Yes, in the sense that go is Turing complete, but no in the sense that there is no tool to do it.

Comment: It is an interesting place to be for a programming language which is so young. Individuals want to decompile code written in it. It means, mission critical code is being written in golang. Kudos to golang at youthful ver 1.4.2

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There is no tool to do that and as Go programs are compiled into machine code, they do not contain enough information to translate them back into Go code. Standard disassembly techniques are still possible though.

Comment: Just because not enough information is compiled into the machine code doesn't mean one can't generate a equivalent golang program out of it

Comment: There's a blog post on the JEB disassembler website on how to extract golang into pseudo-C.  It's not exactly making Golang code, but it lets you figure out what's going on inside an app.

Answer (score 38):

There is no known tool which currently decompiles to Go sources.

Go is a native language compiler, unlike Java and similar languages, which rely on a Class Loader, uses a linker in order to produce its executables.
Therefore just reconstructing the call tree is, as in C and similar languages, a lot harder.

Debug information such as symbols are normally stripped off the Go executable.

There exists very little even in terms of Symbolic debugging of Golang code.

GDB for instance is AFAIK in its current state not aligned with Go architecture and is practically not functional in terms of Golang symbolic debugging. Go GDB has been dropped off IntelliJ ide for this very reason.

There are experimental efforts trying to regain GDB functionality by some users, but these require Go sources to have been compiled with special nonstandard provisions in order to support debugging. e.g.:
http://blog.securitymouse.com/2014/10/golang-debugging-turning-pennies-into-gs.html
Other symbolic debuggers for Go also need insertion of non-standard code in order to support the debugger, e.g. [Hopwatch](http://ernestmicklei.com/2012/12/14/hopwatch-a-debugging-tool-for-go/)

Therefore, if you need to reverse engineer a Go program, you are better off with traditional, lower level reverse engineering tools such as IDA PRO. This is definitely possible, but at most you will get something resembling pseudo-code C, or ASM, never Go sources.

Some feature of the language are non existing in other languages, e.g. channels, and these require some study and a non trivial approach. E.g.: http://jolmos.blogspot.nl/2014/09/inbincible-writeup-golang-binary.html

Comment: Are those things still valid in 2022? ie. no known tool that can decompile a compiled go binary?

Comment: Apparently now it is possible to recover function names from stripped binaries (https://cujo.com/reverse-engineering-go-binaries-with-ghidra/).

Answer (score 5):

Now a day's there is a way to reverse engineer,
But still there is lot of efforts involved after that.

Refer: [GoTools](https://github.com/felberj/gotools)

This works with [Ghidra], (https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/releases), An NSA Tool for Reverse Engineering.

[GoLang Renamer](https://github.com/ghidraninja/ghidra_scripts/blob/master/golang_renamer.py)

This Python script helps in some of post de-compilation tasks to rename.

Note: Before trying any of this, please refer local law that you are not messing up with any proprietary software.