# Reverse engineer go executable

Tags: go, executable, reverse-engineering

I have an executable file and I can say that the source of the file was written in go.Now the file is kind of a secret file(puzzle) and its not revealing much info about what its expecting such as command line arguments.

I have tried using command  line programs such as strings , objdump etc to see if I can get any info on what arguments to pass to the file.But I did not find enough clue.

How can I know if the program is expecting any arguments.(Of course not through guessing.)

Note : I don't have to reverse engineer the whole program.Just wanted to see if there are any keywords which I can use to search the executable to decode any flags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decompiling a compiled program with Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25034065/decompiling-a-compiled-program-with-go)

Comment: If it uses standard flag package, `binary -h` will print help.

Comment: Is binary a shell command ?

Comment: @crackerplace: no, that's the name of your executable

Comment: @SergioTulentsev okk :-)

Comment: check out https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/