# How to convert binary code to go line syntax in main.go

Tags: go, binaries

Few days back code was showing like proper Go syntax. Not sure which command I ran but now main.go code is showing like this. May be this `go build -gcflags='all=-N -l' -o main.go` command converted code to binaries compile code.
[image]

Any idea how to recover back actual code ?

Comment: You overwrote your source file with binary (-o main.go tells compiler to save output as main.go). Unless you have backup your source code is gone.

Comment: I forgot to push latest changes code. Older code I have but I have change many lines.

Comment: Which IDE do you use? If you're lucky enough, maybe the IDE has kept a local file history for you. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46446901/how-can-i-see-local-history-changes-in-visual-studio-code.

Comment: VSCode I used for code.

Comment: Get used to _never_ use filename arguments with the go tool.

Comment: That's what @blami said. Please take no offence, but it appears you do not have any clear idea about what that `go build -gcflags='all=-N -l' -o main.go` incantation really does, and that's the problem. If you did, you weren't be asking your question in the first place. Please don't mindlessly use stuff found on the 'net, always try to make sense of what you've found before using that. In this particular case, run `go help build` or see [this](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies) and learn what the `-o` command-line option does.

Answer (score 2):

The `-o` flag says "compile out to this file," so you overwrote your source with the compiled binary.

There are efforts to reverse engineer a binary, like the things mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25034065/decompiling-a-compiled-program-with-go), but they're not going to get you back your exact code, or probably something even all that readable or complete, depending on how large your program was.

Use [Git](https://git-scm.com/) to track your code, and use a [Makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) or some other build system (even a little batch script) so you don't have to type out the command every time.

Comment: It means not way to get same code. I should be more careful while running this command with -o into main.go.

Comment: Correct. Use a Makefile, shell script, batch file, or whatever, so you can run something like `make build` or `./build.sh` rather than typing it out, and in there, don't put `-o main.go`, put `-o some-other-name`